# Absolute path to symbolic link

Tags: linux, bash, symlink, realpath, readlink

Is there possibility of retrieving absolute path of symbolic file in bash? I cannot use realpath() and readlink() gives path of target. But i need absolute path of that symlink.

Comment: How about `echo "$(readlnk -f $(dirname "$symlink"))/$(basename "$symlink")"` ? Is this what you need?

Comment: `readlink -f link` gives you fullpath

Answer (score 0):

Is this an assignment? I can't imagine a real situation where you would not be allowed to use `readlink` but anyway, just for fun, here is a hack script to get the full path of the symlink provided as argument:

For the example I will use the symlink `pidof` which points to /bin/ usually, but is a symlink to /sbin/killall5 (Ubuntu)

```
#!/bin/bash

linkpath="$(which $1)"

line="$(ls -la $linkpath)"

realpath="$(echo $line | awk '{print $NF}')"

echo "Full path is: $realpath"

exit
```

Output:

```
user@system:~/Desktop$ ./test.sh pidof
Full path is: /sbin/killall5
user@system:~/Desktop$
```

The reason this works is because the output of `ls` shows the full path of symlinks. (At least in Debian distros)

Comment: And i am allowed to use readlink, just not realpath. And yes, its assignment :/

Comment: I know... It was just a hack script for fun. I misread the op, thought he wasn't allowed readlink.